# Agile tools, can't find any that suits my case or I'm wrong somewhere?

Tags: agile, scrum, kanban

We have huge modules in our project, each module has a bunch of user-stories, each story contains developer tasks. Actually, we take tasks from multiple modules, since we have some core module features and optional.

Each developer task I should review and merge into master.

So, basically it is just project-task-subtask, right? But it doesn't fit our case.

1. Each project has it's own board - we need one board, actually
2. Sub-tasks cannot have status beside completed/not. So, sub-task is completed, but not reviewed, but PM sees it like this part is done and ready to be tested and touched. Waiting for whole user story to be completed isn't acceptable every time.

I know it is not a resource to find apps, but I dunno where I can ask this questions.

Comment: I don't understand the statement that a module has user stories. User stories should be attributed to a product, not modules.

Comment: So... "user should be able to create new folder" within "file manager", for example. Without splitting this stories between these "modules", we can't actually say which module needs more attention(we release on really minimum tasks, but should make our product evolve in multiple ways).

Comment: Why does it matter what module needs more attention? Your customers don't understand modules - they see a software system and they need this system to do certain things. I think that AndyBursh's answer is on the right track, except a product may have many projects and I wouldn't tie a story to a component at all, but only to one or more project.

Comment: @ThomasOwens because we have really long list of tasks and features for every module and we can't just throw all hours on statistics module, because ppl will need more in billing module, so we should be able to see where we should work more BEFORE user feedback.

Comment: You say you are doing agile. I think you need to rethink that, since if you aren't responding to the priorities of the users or the user representatives, you aren't doing agile. You prioritize your stories based on the value added and customer feedback, and if that says all the work is in one module, then all the work is in one module. I don't think your tools are the problem, but your process and how you are managing your projects.

Comment: @ThomasOwens we know priorities of users and we set stories based on it. But it means we should take some parts from more than one module. For example, billing and statistics. Each user step has basic things like "pay with PayPal", but when we have completed all tasks with higher priority, we should take, for example, "pay with Bitcoins". This is because we are forced to release product before it is "completed". Is there any wrong thoughts?

Comment: There is no completed product in agile. If you complete a user story, the user should be able to do something. If "pay with bitcoins" is right below "pay with PayPal" in priority, then yes, it should be the next story implemented. When prioritizing stories, you don't consider the design of the software, especially since some stories may cut across your design and affect many things.

Comment: @ThomasOwens so we are doing everything ok, by agile. We prioritize stories based on overall product readiness to be used by users, feedback from users, etc. So if we have billing, which has 2 completed stories(has purse, can view history) and stats with 20(almost all tasks), we should see it, since priority sets on new sprint and PM decides which stories we should take. It is really handy to see that we have no billing in Agile tool. Btw, I'm an Sr. Developer, who tries to simplify PM job and be PM in the future.

Comment: What is "product readiness to be used by users"? That's not how you prioritize stories in any agile method I'm familiar with. You prioritize the stories based on the value they add and set your sprints based on velocity, taking the more important stories from the top of the queue. There's no decision in what stories to implement - you order them by priority and then estimate them. At the end of every sprint, you have a potentially shippable product with new features implemented and bugs fixed.

Comment: "product readiness to be used by users" - for example, user can't use product at all if he has no ability to sign in. I understand what you are talking about. But what, if we can't release product w/o some low-value task, like ability to sign in? Should this task be considered as hign-value task? Btw we can't set priority for each task by start of the project, we had **epics** (which I call modules, as developer), which has some stories now, which we need to implement, so we take 2 tasks from 2 **epics** in one sprint and... we have no tool to split tasks on epics - this is a real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking about what a project is differently to how most of this kind of software does. As a result, you're also breaking down other pieces differently.

In a tool like [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira):

- A **project** is an entire piece of software - a product. So in your case, you have one project.
- Modules within a piece of software are called **components**. In your case, each of the modules would line up 1-to-1 with a component.
- **Stories** (developer tasks) belong to a **project**, and can be associated with 1 or more **components**. Each story has it's own state (open, in progress, done, closed; these are configurable in Jira), and follows a predefined workflow. In your case, a task and a story are equatable.
- A story can be broken down in to **sub-tasks**. Each sub-task (like a story) has it's own state, following a predefined workflow.
- A **backlog** is a collection of stories which need working on. In Jira, this is defined by a filter over all stories in the system.
- A **scrum board** is a team's view on a product **backlog**, showing which stories from that backlog are being worked on in the current sprint. The scrum board has a swimlane (row) for each story, and a column for each state, with stories and subtasks appearing in the appropriate columns.
- A large internal project within the product is an **epic**. An epic can have any number of stories in it.

If you were to use a tool like Jira, you would have a single project, with a scrum board and backlog per team. Stories would be associated with the modules, and work on them would follow the normal workflow.

You could easily divide your teams and backlogs along module boundaries by using an appropriate filter when creating a backlog; eg "only those stories associated with this module"

Comment: Ty! Actually, I tried to split it to things every tool has: project, task, subtask. Yea, Jira has all things I need, all things every project needs! I'm just not a fan of Jira and other tools have problems, like they have only "project-task-subtask". Is there any... alternative tool, which has all this things?

Comment: Also, Jira price is too much for us, sadly...

Comment: JetBrains released YouTrack which is similar.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at YourTrack. 10 users - should be fine, for now. I'm just curious, why all other tools cannot implement such simple things, like you have listed...